# Checking whether user did like the post or not through template tag Django

Tags: python, django

I am using template tag to check whether user liked the question in the feed previously in order to show him  liked "red heart" img or otherwise not. I send user profile and pk of question as arguments to the functions, I want to know whether that user profile is one of that who liked the question. How can I implement it in the right way?

That's my template tag code

```
from django import template
from blog.models import UserProfile
from blog.models import Question
register = template.Library()

def likecheck(theuser, question_pk):
    question_object = Question.objects.get(pk=question_pk)
    # just rude logic of what I seek
    # if theuser in question_object.who_liked:
    #   return true
    # else:
    #   return false

register.filter('likecheck', like check)
```

Relevant piece of class in models.py:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    who_liked = models.ManyToManyField('UserProfile',    
    related_name='who_liked_QUESTION', blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're just missing `.all()` on the end of `question_object.who_liked` in your pseudo code